problema con switch id
Estoy implementando botones en Android studio. Cuando implemento cuatro botones y su switch no de da opción en view.getId() para hacer la vinculación con R.id. No me tengo la opción R.id.
public void onClick(View view) {

        num1=Integer.parseInt(campo1.getText().toString());
        num2=Integer.parseInt(campo2.getText().toString());

        switch (view.getId()){
            
            case R.  //Aqui si pongo case no me da la opcion de ir al Id

                
            

         
            }


        }


Agrega tu build,gradle, indica en que directorio de tu proyecto se encuentra tu clase y agrega que import estas realizando en la clase

Hola, no entiendo bien lo que me quieres decir. Podrías especificarme un poco mas¿? Gracias

Si estas usando una Activity, revisa que el layout que se carga dentro del método onCreate() mediante setContentView() tenga la vista con el id del que tratas de obtener la referencia, en este ejemplo, dentro del archivo activity_main.xml debes asegurar que tiene la vista con el id que tratas de obtener:
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    ...

Pero creo que deberías considerar cambiar tu código para detectar que vista realizaría la acción al dar el clic de la siguiente forma, ejemplo:

Primeramente obtener primeramente el id de la vista
Crear el listener OnClickListener
Asignar el listener a la vista

Para esto te doy este ejemplo:
//* Obtiene la referencia de la vista, en este caso un botón que tiene id mybutton
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.mybutton:
                button1Click();
                break;         
        }
    }
};

//* Asigna el listener
button1.setOnClickListener(listener);

